# Mac OS X - Get state of spacebar

Tags: macos, keyboard

How do I know whether a certain key on the keyboard is pressed/down or unpressed/up on Mac? Right now I need it for the spacebar, but an answer that would work for any key would be perfect.

I don't want to detect the events:

```
-(void)keyDown:(NSEvent*)event;
-(void)keyUp:(NSEvent*)event;
```

I want the state of a key (spacebar) at a certain moment.

On Windows this seems possible (although I haven't tried it out) with the following code:

```
GetAsyncKeyState(VK_SPACE);
```

But I haven't found a solution for Mac yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer [here](http://lists.apple.com/archives/carbon-development/2004/Jul/msg00976.html). This is the working snippet that I used:

```
#include <Carbon/Carbon.h>

Boolean isPressed( unsigned short inKeyCode )
{
    unsigned char keyMap[16];
    GetKeys((BigEndianUInt32*) &keyMap);
    return (0 != ((keyMap[ inKeyCode >> 3] >> (inKeyCode & 7)) & 1));
}
```

`inKeyCode` represents the key of which you want to know whether it is pressed or not. A mapping of keys to `unsigned short`s can be found in the following file on your Mac:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/HIToolbox.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Events.h
```