# How to check if a key is pressed in Electron?

Tags: electron

Is it possible to check if a key is pressed in Electron? I'm not asking to detect *when* a key is pressed.

When my app starts, I want to be able to hold shift while it starts, before the window loads, to open a special menu. An example of what I'm looking for is:

```js
app.whenReady().then(() => {
     const win = new BrowserWindow({ show: false })
     win.loadFile("whatever.html")
     // ***
     const openSpecialMenu = keyboard.shiftKeyHeld
     // ***
     // do other stuff
     window.show()
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if there's an easy way to do this, but I believe you can do this using native APIs.

On Windows you can use [`GetKeyState`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getkeystate).

On macOS you can use [the function described in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16283140/9698583).

You can then build a [native node addon](https://nodejs.org/api/addons.html) that allows you to use these native APIs in your Electron JavaScript code.

In fact, I found a node module for Windows that does what you need: https://github.com/Zysen/node-asynckeystate

You need to do additional work to support other operating systems.