# Execute function more than once while key is pressed (ncurses)

Tags: c, macos, curses

I would like to be able to run the function `execlp(...)` more than once when pressing the right key (this works only on mac, it basically uses `oasascript` to press the corresponding key for increasing the brightness as I know these special keys can't be simulated with ncurses).

The program compiles and runs, but when I press the right key, it increases the brightness once then interrupts. I would like to keep it running so when the right key is pressed again to repeat the action while the key is kept pressed.

```c
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int key = 0;

  initscr();
  noecho();
  curs_set(TRUE);
  keypad(stdscr, TRUE);
  nodelay(stdscr, TRUE);

  while(1) {
    clear();

    refresh();
    key = getch();

    if (key == KEY_RIGHT) {
      execlp(
        "osascript",
        "osascript",
        "-e",
        "tell application \"System Events\" to key code 144 using {option down, shift down}",
        NULL
      );
    }
  }
  endwin();
}
```

Comment: `execlp` will replace current process with newly executed command, so you will have to use `fork()` to create new process for running new command.

Comment: Windows, Linux?

Comment: @ryyker on mac, I have specified in the description. `oascript` is a osx specific command

Comment: So you did, sorry. Missed that.  I found [this about that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16283140)

Answer (score 0):

By its nature, you can't run `execlp()` more than once, but you can replace it with `fork()` or the like. But my preference would be to look for a direct API solution to control the brightness, rather than launching a separate process to fake a keypress. To that end, I found this: [Adjust screen brightness in Mac OS X app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32691397/adjust-screen-brightness-in-mac-os-x-app)

Comment: Thanks, but you are pointing to a `swift` solution and I am intersted in a `C` implementation. There is already a nice low level implementation for in `C` as well here: https://github.com/nriley/brightness, but this has the caveat of not updating the brightness slider to the value you are setting via the app. Anyway, in my case I have solved it by using `system()` instead of `execlp()`